# When talking about ANSI SQL, is there a difference between JOIN and LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql

I had an interview today where they asked the question, "Tell me the difference between a JOIN and INNER JOIN."  I proceeded to explain what INNER JOIN is, and started to talk about LEFT JOIN.  The interviewer interrupted me and said, "No I didn't say LEFT JOIN, just JOIN."  I was honestly stuck because I never used "JOIN" I always specified LEFT JOIN.

He told me that LEFT JOIN and JOIN act the same.  When looking up "JOIN" I can't find any information saying that it works just like left join.

Does JOIN work the same as LEFT JOIN?
Is it normal, for tech/IT jobs, to have trick questions like this?

Answer (score 1):

Plain old `JOIN` is a synonym for `INNER JOIN`.  That is quite different from a `LEFT JOIN`

SQL implements through explicit syntax five `JOIN` operations:

- `CROSS JOIN`
- `INNER JOIN`
- `LEFT JOIN`
- `RIGHT JOIN`
- `FULL JOIN`

In addition, "join" can colloquially mean "combining rows from two tables" and there are other join types -- such as semi-joins.

Comment: Interesting thank you!  The interviewer told me that JOIN was the same as LEFT JOIN.  Not sure how I feel about him not knowing the answer to his own trick question.

Comment: @MyNameHere . . . I wonder if that was some sort of test.  Perhaps you were supposed to respond "Hmmm, I don't think so.  I'm pretty sure it is just an `INNER JOIN`."

Comment: good point!  That would make sense why he was correcting me.  At the very least I learned something new from the interview!